# New to python trying to understand why a stored procedure will not accept a string as input please see below

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am relatively new to python, but have worked on windows for quite awhile, 
I am trying to learn python for kicks.

All below examples are on a rasberry pie b+; python is version 3.7, Mysql Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

See problem below

Also a second question

```
t1 = tuple('cat')
```

If I take the input  cat  which is a string and try to convert to tuple I get ('c' 'a' 't')

I would like it to be ('cat',) How do you do this

The stored procedure for both examples

```
DELIMITER $$
 2
 3 CREATE PROCEDURE animal_list(IN lname char(50))
 4 BEGIN
 5 if lname = '' then
 6         select * from animals;
 7 else
 8         select * from animals where tname = lname;
 9 end if;
10 END$$
11
12 DELIMITER ;
```

Problem: if I do cursor.callpeoc and send it a string I get the following issues

Trying to understand why a stored procedure will not except a string as a "in" value

See examples below

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 730, in
 callproc
    raise ValueError("args must be a sequence")
ValueError: args must be a sequence

The error comes after line 27

Code that produces the error

```
# call stored procedure and get back a dictionary and use keys to print value
 2 import mysql.connector
 3 import ast
 4 from mysql.connector.conversion import MySQLConverter
 5 from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
 6 import pprint
 7 # Create initial connection
 8 printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1)
 9 db = mysql.connector.connect(
10   option_files="/home/pi/my.ini" )
11 print(
12   "Initial MySQL connection ID ...: {0}"
13   .format(db.connection_id) )
14
15
16 cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True,dictionary=True)
17 args  = input('Enter a animal name: '))
23 t1 = args
27 cursor.callproc('animal_list',t1)
28

29 # lookd line a stored procedure always returns a list
30
31 for result in cursor.stored_results():
32       print ('total rows = ' + str(result.rowcount))
33
34       # next 2 lines create a dictionary
35       cnl = [x[0] for x in result.description] # get the keys from the cursor
36       rd = [dict(zip(cnl,row)) for row in result.fetchall()]   # create the dictionary
37       #print ('rd = ' + str(rd))
38       #for key in rd:
39       #      for item in rd[key]:
40       #          print (key, ':', item)
41       count = 0
42
43       for r  in rd:
44           for item in r.keys():
45           #    print ('key = ' + item)
46
47               print ( 'key  = ' + str(item) + ' value = ' + str(r[item]))
48 cursor.close()
49 db.close()
50 #t1 = '(' + args + ',)'
51 #t1 = tuple(args)
52 #args1 = make_tuble(args)
53 #print ('args = ' + str(type(args)))
54 #cursor.callproc('animal_list', args)
55
```

However if i send it a list or tuple it works ok
code follows

```
# call stored procedure and get back a dictionary and use keys to print value
 2 import mysql.connector
 3 import ast
 4 from mysql.connector.conversion import MySQLConverter
 5 from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
 6 import pprint
 7 # Create initial connection
 8 printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1)
 9 db = mysql.connector.connect(
10   option_files="/home/pi/my.ini" )
11 print(
12   "Initial MySQL connection ID ...: {0}"
13   .format(db.connection_id) )
14
15
16 cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True,dictionary=True)
17 #args  = eval(input('Enter a animal name: '))
18
19 args = input ('enter a animal name ')
20 b = args.split(" ")
21
22 t1  = b
23 cursor.callproc('animal_list',t1)
24
25 # lookd line a stored procedure always returns a list
26
27 for result in cursor.stored_results():
28       print ('total rows = ' + str(result.rowcount))
29
30       # next 2 lines create a dictionary
31       cnl = [x[0] for x in result.description] # get the keys from the cursor
32       rd = [dict(zip(cnl,row)) for row in result.fetchall()]   # create the dictionary
33       #print ('rd = ' + str(rd))
34       #for key in rd:
35       #      for item in rd[key]:
36       #          print (key, ':', item)
37       count = 0
38
39       for r  in rd:
40           for item in r.keys():
41           #    print ('key = ' + item)
42
43               print ( 'key  = ' + str(item) + ' value = ' + str(r[item]))
44 cursor.close()
45 db.close()
```

Comment: "I would like it to be ('cat',) How do you do this" You just did...

Comment: Try to omit the line numbers when posting code. It makes it difficult for others to copy/paste your code into their own editors when trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `cursor.callproc()` method takes as input the name of the stored procedure and its parameters must be passed as a sequence (list, tuple, etc). That's the reason why you get a `ValueError: args must be a sequence` when you pass a string. You can see some examples [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-python/).

About the question of how to construct a tuple with `tuple()`. You can pass any iterable to it (like the string in your example), and it will build a tuple from the iterable's items. Examples:

- string: `tuple('cat') == ('c', 'a', 't')`
- tuple: `tuple('cat',) == ('cat',)`
- list: `tuple(['cat']) == ('cat',)`

From your example, it would be easier to simply do `t1 = 'cat',`,